# The entity or complex type 'DatabaseNameModel.Categories' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My model class is

```
public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public int? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Children { get; set; }
    }
```

My database has the following values

```
CategoryID CategoryName ParentCategoryID ChildrenCategoryID
    1      CAT 1        NULL             NULL
    2      CAT 2        NULL             NULL
    3      CAT 3        NULL             NULL
    4      Child 1.1    1                NULL
    5      Child 2  2   2                NULL
    6      Child 2.1    1                NULL
```

While trying to fill the Children Categories

```
var query = from row in db.Categories select new Categories
   {
      CategoryID = row.CategoryID,
      CategoryName = row.CategoryName,
      ParentCategoryID = row.ParentCategoryID,
      Children = db.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryID == row.CategoryID).ToList()
   };
```

I get the error

```
The entity or complex type 'DatabaseNameModel.Categories' cannot be constructed 
in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

So here are a couple of questions

1. How can i fix that?
2. That `ChildrenCategoryID` from where it was generated from?

**Update**

All above are used to create a recursive menu in MVC

Comment: what actually you want to  achieve?

Comment: @varocarbas it was auto generated in the .edmx file

Comment: @SherifAhmed i would like to fill the Categories1

Comment: @varocarbas I think he is trying to do a self join ... so the 'Children' Property must not exists. not the Categories1

Comment: I realise now that you are providing misleading information: why do you include the definition of ´Category´ when the query deals with the class ´Categories´?! Please provide the proper information (= definition of the class ´Categories´)

Comment: Just a simple query with projection but in fact you don't have any class `Categories`. Don't understand what you actually want.

Comment: @SherifAhmed This question doesn't make any sense. The class definition is not related to the one being affected by the query. The OP has firstly to provide the proper information; and then explain what is expected.

Comment: I do accept what you said as I realize that too

Comment: @varocarbas Regarding the misleading info. This was generated by visual studio, not me. I edited the linq query to reflect what i am asking for

Comment: ***new Categories*** - this means you have a class `Categories`, isn't that? why not show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Chocol8

for a self join sql the structure would be

```
CategoryID CategoryName ParentCategoryID
    1      CAT 1        NULL             
    2      CAT 2        NULL             
    3      CAT 3        NULL             
    4      Child 1.1    1                
    5      Child 2  2   2                
    6      Child 2.1    1
```

because the the Category may have more than one children

and the Model it that case the model will be (or something like that)

```
public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public int? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual ParentCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

so if you got ef to work correctly you must specify the relation correctly in SQL structure ...

or use the second approach for "code first"

I hope this helps

Comment: Why did you say above that you understood my point, when you didn't. You cannot answer what doesn't make any sense. The OP tries to modify the class ´Categories´, whose definition is not being shown at  all. The provided definition of `Category` doesn't have any relationship with it. You can declare two completely different classes with equivalent names.

Comment: Even if what you are saying is true 100%, but may be he misunderstanding some thing or he is still learning some other thing ... so the purpose here in Stack-overflow is to help others not to show that the OP is trying to cheat us, be cool my friend (I know that you are right :))

Comment: Cheat us? Why? No. The question doesn't make any sense = there is no valid answer. Example of not-answerable question: "how do you say good day in the language I have invented right now and you don't know anything about?" -> you cannot answer that. Equivalently to this question. Independently upon what I might think about certain attitudes, there is an objective reality here: the asked qqestion cannot be answered, because no valid information about the problem has been provided! You are proposing a blind guess which cannot be considered an accurate answer (at any level).